# What is the correct way to run a function whenever a session variable changes in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to run a function whenever any session variable out of a given set changes. Currently I do it like this:

```
Meteor.autorun( ->
    Session.get("var1")
    Session.get("var2")
    runMyFunction()
)
```

This works, but seems a little awkward as the dependencies are very artificial. Is there a cleaner way of achieving the same goal?

To add some context to the story:
In real life, I want to reset the animation state (class) of loading images when my layout changes. These session variables control the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Theres nothing wrong with using the design you're using. If you want to use something more specific and custom tuned have a look at [Deps.dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency) which should let you create custom reactive functions/variables.

EventedMind has a good videocast on how to create one at : http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source

Of small note is `Meteor.autorun` is being depreciated in favour of `Deps.autorun`

**Update : Small Example:

```
var cssClass = "cls1";
var cssDep = new Deps.Dependency;

getCssClass = function () {
    cssDep.depend()
    return cssClass;
};

setCssClass = function (w) {
    if(w!=cssClass) {
        cssClass = w;
        cssDep.changed();
        runMyFunction();
    }
};
```

Then use `setCssClass(newvalue)` and `getCssClass()` to set and get the value respectively, instead of the `Session` `get` and `set` methods

Comment: What is wrong is that it is semantically ugly. I don't need the values of `var1` and `var2` so it makes no sense to use `get`

Comment: I think I confused what you mean't at first and now I get what you mean. The Deps.dependency might be the best way to go to directly hook up runMyFunction()

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to do it. Can you add an example?

Comment: Thanks. But it is way too complicated to be used in my opinion. It could be nice if I could expose the `Session` var dependency object to set a `depend()`